Does not output what is linked to the callback function
@router.callback_query(F.date == 'go')
async def ISP(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer('перейдите',reply_markup=kb.main)

@router.callback_query(F.date == 'gos')
async def ISP(message: Message):
    await message.answer('выберете курс',reply_markup=kb.isp) 


ras = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[[InlineKeyboardButton(text='ИСП',callback_data='gos')],
                                       [InlineKeyboardButton(text='ПД',callback_data='god')],
[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад",callback_data='go')],
                                       [InlineKeyboardButton(text='МНЭЭ',callback_data='goh'),

                                       InlineKeyboardButton(text='СД',callback_data='gok')]],
                           resize_keyboard=True,
                           input_field_placeholder='Выберете группу')

I added all the functions, I have no errors, the bot just ignores the button on which the callback is located, this is part of the code, the rest works fine

Where do you hook the callback to the button?

I can add all the code, but I didn't really check what you mean.

Was that supposed to be F.data instead of F.date?

Clarify what you mean by 'ignores the button'. Is the callback not triggered or is the response not as expected?

Thank you all, the error was in the syntax
